# Global variables get and set in an Angular app

Tags: angular, internationalization, ngx-translate, angular-i18n

How can I get and set global vars in Angular 8? The problem is, if I create a file like that

```
export class SharedService {
    globalLanguage:string;

    setGlobalVar(currentLanguage:string) {
      this.globalLanguage = currentLanguage;
    }
    getGlobalVar():string{
      return this.globalLanguage;
    }
  }
```

and I try to set from a component by set function, by reading from an other component by get function  the variable is `undefined`. I searched several example but they are referred only to global constant and not to a global variable which I can change or update. How can I solve the problem?

### Edit

I also tried in this way but with the same result, the variable is undefined.

Here is the global var injectable service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})

export class SharedService {
    private globalLanguage:string;

    setGlobalVar(currentLanguage:string) {
      this.globalLanguage = currentLanguage;
    }

    getGlobalVar():string{

        return this.globalLanguage;
    }
  }
```

This is how I set from the component 1:

```
import { SharedService } from '../../../shared/vars'

@Component({

  providers: [SharedService],
  selector: 'app-user-menu',
  templateUrl: './user-menu.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user-menu.component.scss']
})
export class UserMenuComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public translate: TranslateService , public ls: SharedService) {
     (...)
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  languageSwitcher(currentLanguage: string){

    // This is the set point!
    this.ls.setGlobalVar(currentLanguage);
  }
}
```

And this is the way I read from component 2, with result "undefined":

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';
    import { SharedService } from '../../shared/vars'

    @Component({

      providers: [SharedService],
      selector: 'app-administration',
      templateUrl: './administration-main.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./administration-main.component.scss']
    })
    export class AdministrationMainComponent implements OnInit {

      constructor(public translate: TranslateService, public ls: SharedService) {
     //This is the output point!        
     console.log('test' + ls.getGlobalVar());
      }

      ngOnInit() {
      }
    }
```

Comment: It should work globally where you inject the service, the only reason it could happen is that you called the `get` before the `set`

Comment: The other reasons for it not working would be adding `SharedService` to the `providers` arrays in different places of the project (which would instantiate more than one instance of `SharedService`).

Comment: @TheUnreal no, I set by option before calling.  you can see in the code above, is called in the correct point (I hope, if I didn't do something wrong). Thank for your helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make this class a service with @Injectable decorator and provided in the root of your application. After that in each of your components where you want to use it you need to instantiate it in the constructor.

```
constructor(public sharedService: SharedService) ()
```

and then you will have access to your functions.

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't work, also in your way I read "undefined" output. I edited the original question with a complete code.

Comment: I dont see you calling this.languageSwitcher() anywhere. And the console log in the end should be      console.log('test',  this.ls.getGlobalVar());

Comment: remove the sharedService from the providers arrray from both components. That is your problem. It is now provided in the root.

Comment: thank you very much, is called by html option which sure works (there is also other action there, as other test output, which I don't write in post to not be annoyng. Also changed the console.log instruction, same result. :-( But thank you very much, other solutions?

Comment: As I said, remove the providers arrays from both components. You are already doing 'providedIn: root' .  I am pretty sure it will work after that.

Answer (score 2):

use @Injectable for your service

import that service in your class and inject in your constructor. if you want to load a variable or call a function on load of class call it inside constructor or else outside of it

```
    constructor(private sharedService: SharedService) {
        this.name= sharedService.name;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your helping, I editet the original question with my code. I used Injectable but with the same result. How can I solve? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Remove SharedService from providers array. It is creating multiple instance of SharedService

Answer (score 0):

To achieve We use a technique called "rxjs state control variable = RSTC". This can be applied in angular easily but we also use it in Next.js.

You will have to consider the following files (names of files an variables can be changed to any thing you want). This is just an example.

RSTC is a Subject Behavior rxjs object, and can have as many properties as you like. You can make one huge RSTC or many small ones. I prefer the second method, as it is less messy, and I use usually one per angular module.

**Procedure:**

- Create a file for the state model
- Create a file for the service
- Import in the the service in the constructor of the component (or components) where you want to use it
  -- can be used in several ways, basically as a private variable or as a public variable (the results are basically the same)

The difference using public or private properties is that public can be used in the html directly, private only works in the typescript file. If you want to show the data you would have to create a local variable and assign the private imported value to it.

Then you can make any change to any property of that imported value with any function or method.

If you display the value in the html, the value will change automatically in all components that use the same imported service...

**Sample code:**

...models/config.state.ts

```
    export class ConfigState {
      language: string = 'en'
      languageOptions: string[] = ['es', 'pl', 'br']
      timeZone: string = 'America/Caracas'
      secretMessage: string = 'Hello world'
    }
```

Then create a service importing the previous file

.../services/config-state.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ConfigState } from '../models/config.state';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class ConfigStateService {
  private subject = new BehaviorSubject<ConfigState>(new ConfigState());
  state = this.subject.asObservable();

  storeConfig = new ConfigState(); // this is the variable you will use

  constructor() {
    this.state.subscribe((state) => (this.storeConfig = state));
  }
}
```

Then create a component and import the service (I will use the public option because is easier to understand, but can be used as a private variable and assign the service value to it)

test.component.ts

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';
    import { ConfigStateService } from '../services/config-state.service';

    @Component({
      selector: 'test',
      templateUrl: './test.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./test.component.scss'],
    })
    export class TestComponent {
      constructor(public config: ConfigStateService) {}
    }
```

test.component.html

```
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="config.storeConfig.secretMessage">
    <p>{{config.storeConfig.secretMessage}}</p>
```

---

You can import the RSCV in multiple components but if you change the value in any component, all others will reflect the changes immediately.

One last thing, I recommend to initialize with default values as shown in this example, other wise you will have 'undefined' problems